# Anchor tag within div and ul won't work

Tags: html, html-lists, anchor

I am playing around with an HTML template. I made a un-ordered list that enables the visitor to choose between two languages. Within it, i placed an anchor tag, and within the tag an image corresponding to chosen language, accompanied by some text. Though i have don't this before, for some reason, when i try to test the page on Firefox or Chrome the anchor tag won't work. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance for your time.

Code:

```
     <div class="polyglot-language-switcher" style="margin-top:10px;float:right;">
        <ul>
            <li style="display:inline;margin-right:2px;"><a href="servicesEnglish.html" title="English (US)" ><img src="images/us.png" alt="English"> English (US)</a></li>
            <li style="display:inline;"><a href="#" title="Greek"><img src="images/gr.png" alt="Greek"> Ελληνικά</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

EDIT:
I do not know, if this has any value, but i initially copied the code from this site http://www.ixtendo.com/polyglot-language-switcher-2/.  But i only copied the HTML bit.

Comment: This code works, problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Download the Zip file from this link 
https://github.com/ixtendo/Polyglot-Language-Switcher/archive/master.zip
and extract it and open the index.html file.... that is what you want.